# php frameworks in web services?

Tags: php, cakephp, symfony1, web-hosting, yii

Hello I've been searching for a web hosting site that enables php frameworks, e.g. yii, cakephp, symfony, or are you forced to have an own server if you want that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you explain a little more please ? i don't understand your question

Comment: Do you mean "web hosting"? Many allow you to upload your own framework, whichever you're using; few will come with the framweork pre-installed. (btw "web service": that is something rather different)

Comment: oh I'm sorry I mean web hosting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you don't need to own the server, if you can upload a php file, most of the time it's ok.
For example CakePHP Requierement page tell you :

> HTTP Server. For example: Apache. mod_rewrite is preferred, but by no means required.
>   PHP 4.3.2 or greater. Yes, CakePHP works great on PHP 4 and 5.
>   Source : http://book.cakephp.org/view/28/Requirements

Answer (score 2):

Yes , your server side should support PHP  and the framework also 
[A beginners guide to PHP Frameworks](http://grindsmart.com/2010/01/php-frameworks-a-beginners-quick-guide/)

Answer (score 2):

---

read framework documentation what php version it supports also.

Answer (score 1):

You can run those frameworks on any web host that has PHP support. Just upload the framework files and your code and you're ready.

Comment: Are you sure? There is no executible or similar that is needed. I asked one site that use php and they said no, but maybe he didin't know?

Comment: @Elias that's just for the development tools. Some frameworks have CLI scaffolding scripts. But you normally only use those on your development environment, and just upload the final application+framework. Therefore there are no specific server requirements or shell access necessary.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the framework you are willing to use.

With symfony, you'll need to have an access to the shell (command line). 
Check the specifications on the frameworks requirements